# How to pass JSON data from ListView to new activity

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview

I have created a `ListView` that is populated with `JSON` data, and I have included `OnItemClickListener` to open a new `Activity` through `Intent`. What I'm trying to do is to make that new `Activity` generate data based on the item I have clicked in the `ListView`.

For example, if I clicked item from `JSON` field name `JohnDoe` in the `ListView`, I want to generate page with information from another `JSON` data file. And concrete example would be like the Google Play Store.

I click some app and it opens a page with populated info about that app.

Edit: I have tried that passing object link, and it doesnt work. I have getter and setter in a class, then I parse it in my main class.

Example here:

```
  JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Movie movie = new Movie();
                                    movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
```

Comment: where is your approach ?? Too old question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082122/passing-jsonobject-into-another-activity Refer this link

Comment: I was trying that from the refer link, but it is not working. So thats why i placed this question for a detailed explanation. You need not down vote it if you haven't heard what i had to say more..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send an object as a parameter to another activity if the object implements **Parcelable**:

[A typical implementation of Parcelable here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

Then, to send like parameter, something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailMovieActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", movie);//Your object that implements Parcelable
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the other activity:

```
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
Movie movie = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("key"));//Receive object
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like the Parcelable approach or do not know how to do it you can simply pass the JSONObject as a String like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5300417/3647974).

The only thing you have to worry about is retrieving the right JSONObject inside your OnItemClickListener.